# Adding class to elements based on their data attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on the following example. How I can use the data attribute `data-st=""` to filter adding class to element as below? For example I am trying to add the `.red` to ONLY element which have `data-st="red"`

```js
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('red');
        });
    });
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Apply</button>

<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="black"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="blue"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `[data-st=red]`

```js
$("#a1").click(function(){
        $("p[data-st!=red]").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('red');
        });
    });
    
    $("#a1").click(function(){
        $("p[data-st!=red]").each(function(){
            $(this).addClass('red');
        });
    });
```

```css
.red{color:red;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a1">Apply 1</button>
<button id="a2">Apply 2</button>

<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="black"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="blue"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
```

**EDIT** To answer your question in the comment

> Thanks sam this is perfect. but just one more question ? How about to
>   add the class to all other attribute BUT NOT to red ones? – Mona Coder
>   3 mins ago

You can do that in a few ways:

- Using the `[data-st!=red]`
- Using the `.not()` method `$('p').not('p[data-st=red]')`

```js
$("#a1").click(function() {
  $("p[data-st!=red]").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
  });
});
$("#a2").click(function() {
  $("p").not("p[data-st=red]").each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('red');
  });
});
```

```css
.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="a1">Apply 1</button>
<button id="a2">Apply 2</button>

<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="black"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="blue"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
```

Comment: Thanks sam this is perfect. but just one more question ? How about to add the class to all other attribute BUT NOT to red ones?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a more specific selector like `p[data-st="red"]`

Also, jquery methods (*unless they return a value*) will apply to all elements in the selection. So in your case you can skip the `.each`

```
$('p[data-st="red"]').addClass('red');
```

If your logic is more complicate and you want to do different things according to the value of the attribute you can use the `.data` to extract the value and act accordingly

```
$('p[data-st]').each(function(){
   var self = $(this),
       st = self.data('st');

   switch (st){
        case "red":
                  // do things here if data-st was red
                  self.addClass('red');
                  break;
        case "green":
                  // do things here if data-st was green
                  break;
        default:  
                  // do things here if data-st did not match any of the above cases 
   }   

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this solution by using jquery filter method

```js
  $(function(){
   $('button').click(function(){
    $('p').filter('[data-st="red"]').addClass('red');
   })
});
```

```css
.red{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Apply</button>

<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="black"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="red"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="blue"> App </p>
<p class="" data-st="green"> App </p>
```